# What is the correct way to add_done_callback in grpc?

Tags: grpc-python

If I `add_done_callback` to a grpc future object, did I need to close channel?

```py
class CallBack(object):
    def __init__(self,channel=None) -> None:
        self._channel = channel

    def __call__(self, future):
        print(self.future.result())
        # self._channel.close()
def test():
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
    stub = helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterStub(channel)
    call_future = stub.SayHello.future(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'))
    call_back = CallBack(channel)
    call_future.add_done_callback(call_back)
```

If I use `with-statement` to initialize channel, channel will close before callback.

```py
def test():
    with grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051') as channel:
        stub = helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterStub(channel)
        call_future = stub.SayHello.future(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'))
        call_back = CallBack(channel)
        call_future.add_done_callback(call_back)
```

Which will raise error:

```
cription":"Channel closed!","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":727,"grpc_message":"Channel closed!","grpc_status":1}"
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to close the channel *at some point*. The alternative is leaking per-channel memory as you spin up more channels in your process over time. The problem in your second example with the `with` statement is that the channel is closed before the callback has a chance to fire.

If the callback executing is the point at which the channel is no longer needed, then you should close the channel from that callback or set a bit of state indicating that another thread should close the channel.